# D3 X Axis Text and Tick Line Not Visible

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having an issue with a D3 chart where my x axis text and tick lines are invisible. I can see both elements placed properly in web inspector on the chart, and I have stroke and stroke width on the tick lines, but I think I'm missing another piece. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
var parentContainer = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('#svgContainer'));
var margins = {top: 40, right: 20. bottom: 20, left: 20};
var svgWidth = parentContainer.width;
var svgHeight = parentContainer.height;
var height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;

var svg = d3.select('svgContainer')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', svgWidth)
.attr('height', svgHeight)
.attr('transform, 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient('top')
.innerTickSize(-height);

 svg.append('g')
.attr('class', 'xAxis')
.call(xAxis);
```

And here is my CSS/LESS:

```
#svgContainer {
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
.tick {
  line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
  }
  text {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

I didn't include the rest of my chart code as it seems to be working correctly - the axis lines and text are in the correct spots and at the correct intervals, just not visible. Not sure what I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate, I answered this same question/problem a while ago, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the height/width that includes the subtracted margin values.

```
var height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;

var svg = d3.select('svgContainer')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height)
.attr('transform, 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#api-reference), you're gonna see:

> Regardless of orientation, axes are always rendered at the origin.

So, your axis is there, but on the very top of the SVG, and you can't see it.

**Solution**: You have to translate it down:

```
svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'xAxis')
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
```

Here is a demo with your(*) code:

```js
var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20};
var svgWidth = 500;
var svgHeight = 200;
var height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', svgWidth)
.attr('height', svgHeight)
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

var x = d3.scale.linear()
 .range([0, width]);

 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient('top')
.innerTickSize(-height);

 svg.append('g')
.attr('class', 'xAxis')
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + margin.top + ")")
.call(xAxis);
```

```css
path, line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: black;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

*: your code is *full* of problems, from undefined variables and properties to missing quotes. I suggest you revise it. Besides that, there is no point in translating an SVG (which doesn't work), that part of the code requires a group instead.